# How long Apple will keep trying charge for failed auto renewable subscription?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription

We are doing auto renewal from server side by verifying receipt with Apple's API.
According to [Apple's doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW3):

> During the 24-hour period before the subscription expires, the App Store starts trying to automatically renew it. The App Store makes several attempts to automatically renew the subscription over a period of time but eventually stops if there are too many failed attempts.

So we can start querying 24 hours before it expires with cronjob, but I'm wondering how many times or how long Apple will try to renew when failed. In other words, after how long, I can consider the subscription will no longer be renewed?